# When selecting inputs by name, does using "input" before the name selector change the speed of the search?

Tags: jquery

When selecting a form input by name, you can use this syntax:

```
$("#formId").find("[name='foo']").val();
```

But you can also put `input` before the name selector:

```
$("#formId").find("input[name='foo']").val();
```

Both produce the same result.

Which is better in terms of speed? Does it matter?

This may seem trivial, but whenever there's more than one way of doing something, I always try to determine which is better and then stick with it consistently.

Comment: since attribute selector is one of the slowest adding an element selector should speed it up.. still I prefer you to do a benchmark test in http://jsperf.com/

Comment: but it looks like my assumption is wrong - http://jsperf.com/jquery-attribute-selector-with-element-selector

Comment: That's really interesting. I had never run across that benchmarking website before, thanks for sharing. Would you like to make your comments an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in the comments, my initial assumption was using the element selector will make the selector faster...

As as per the [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attribute-selector-with-element-selector) I tested in [jspref](http://jsperf.com/), it looks like the one without the element selector is faster... even though very negligible